# SQL 2008 - The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL syntax like so:

```
SELECT a.Job_No, 
       a.ContractReceived_F, 
       a.DesignReview_F, 
       z.OrderPlotPlan_S, 
       a.OrderPlotPlan_F, 
       z.OrderTrusses_S, 
       a.OrderTrusses_F, 
       z.OrderHeatCalcs_S, 
       a.OrderHeatCalcs_F, 
       z.PermitRelease_S, 
       a.PermitRelease_F, 
       a.IntSelectionsAppt_F, 
       z.ExcavationFile_S, 
       a.ExcavationFile_F, 
       z.FramingFile_S, 
       a.FramingFile_F, 
       z.FinishingFile_S, 
       a.FinishingFile_F, 
       a.StartDate, 
       a.Possession, 
       c.Expected_Occupancy AS ClosingDate, 
       m.Description, 
       m.ActualFinish       AS LastTaskCompleted 
FROM   (SELECT a.Job_No, 
               a.ContractReceived_F, 
               a.DesignReview_F, 
               z.OrderPlotPlan_S, 
               Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.Job_No) AS RowNum 
        FROM   dbo.ScheduledatesFF AS a 
               INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomers AS c 
                       ON a.Job_No = c.Job_No 
               INNER JOIN dbo.scheduledatesSS AS z 
                       ON a.Job_No = z.Job_No 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.maxscheddate AS m 
                            ON a.Job_No = m.Job_No) AS SOD 
WHERE  SOD.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 2
```

But I get this error for each item in my first select:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.Job_No" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.ContractReceived_F" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.DesignReview_F" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "z.OrderPlotPlan_S" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.OrderPlotPlan_F" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "z.OrderTrusses_S" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.OrderTrusses_F" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "z.OrderHeatCalcs_S" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.OrderHeatCalcs_F" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "z.PermitRelease_S" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.PermitRelease_F" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.IntSelectionsAppt_F" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "z.ExcavationFile_S" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.ExcavationFile_F" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "z.FramingFile_S" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.FramingFile_F" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "z.FinishingFile_S" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.FinishingFile_F" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.StartDate" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "a.Possession" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "c.Expected_Occupancy" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "m.Description" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "m.ActualFinish" could not be bound.
```

I am very new at SQL and I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out, this is way to advanced for me, any help would be much appreciated.

I tried removing the aliases and changing them to SOD and now I get these errors:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'OrderPlotPlan_F'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'OrderTrusses_S'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'OrderTrusses_F'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'OrderHeatCalcs_S'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'OrderHeatCalcs_F'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'PermitRelease_S'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'PermitRelease_F'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'IntSelectionsAppt_F'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'ExcavationFile_S'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'ExcavationFile_F'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'FramingFile_S'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'FramingFile_F'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'FinishingFile_S'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'FinishingFile_F'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'StartDate'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Possession'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Expected_Occupancy'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Description'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'ActualFinish'.
```

On this query:

```
SELECT SOD.Job_No, 
       SOD.ContractReceived_F, 
       SOD.DesignReview_F, 
       SOD.OrderPlotPlan_S, 
       SOD.OrderPlotPlan_F, 
       SOD.OrderTrusses_S, 
       SOD.OrderTrusses_F, 
       SOD.OrderHeatCalcs_S, 
       SOD.OrderHeatCalcs_F, 
       SOD.PermitRelease_S, 
       SOD.PermitRelease_F, 
       SOD.IntSelectionsAppt_F, 
       SOD.ExcavationFile_S, 
       SOD.ExcavationFile_F, 
       SOD.FramingFile_S, 
       SOD.FramingFile_F, 
       SOD.FinishingFile_S, 
       SOD.FinishingFile_F, 
       SOD.StartDate, 
       SOD.Possession, 
       SOD.Expected_Occupancy AS ClosingDate, 
       SOD.Description, 
       SOD.ActualFinish       AS LastTaskCompleted 
FROM   (SELECT a.Job_No, 
               a.ContractReceived_F, 
               a.DesignReview_F, 
               z.OrderPlotPlan_S, 
               Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.Job_No) AS RowNum 
        FROM   dbo.ScheduledatesFF AS a 
               INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomers AS c 
                       ON a.Job_No = c.Job_No 
               INNER JOIN dbo.scheduledatesSS AS z 
                       ON a.Job_No = z.Job_No 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.maxscheddate AS m 
                            ON a.Job_No = m.Job_No) AS SOD 
WHERE  SOD.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 2
```

UPDATE:

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT SOD.Job_No, 
       SOD.ContractReceived_F, 
       SOD.DesignReview_F, 
       SOD.OrderPlotPlan_S, 
       SOD.OrderPlotPlan_F, 
       SOD.OrderTrusses_S, 
       SOD.OrderTrusses_F, 
       SOD.OrderHeatCalcs_S, 
       SOD.OrderHeatCalcs_F, 
       SOD.PermitRelease_S, 
       SOD.PermitRelease_F, 
       SOD.IntSelectionsAppt_F, 
       SOD.ExcavationFile_S, 
       SOD.ExcavationFile_F, 
       SOD.FramingFile_S, 
       SOD.FramingFile_F, 
       SOD.FinishingFile_S, 
       SOD.FinishingFile_F, 
       SOD.StartDate, 
       SOD.Possession, 
       SOD.Expected_Occupancy AS ClosingDate, 
       SOD.Description, 
       SOD.ActualFinish       AS LastTaskCompleted 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.Job_No) AS RowNum 
        FROM   dbo.ScheduledatesFF AS a 
               INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomers AS c 
                       ON a.Job_No = c.Job_No 
               INNER JOIN dbo.scheduledatesSS AS z 
                       ON a.Job_No = z.Job_No 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.maxscheddate AS m 
                            ON a.Job_No = m.Job_No) AS SOD 
WHERE  SOD.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 2
```

and got this error:

```
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The column 'Job_No' was specified multiple times for 'SOD'.
```

UPDATE This fixed my issue:

```
SELECT SOD.Job_No, 
       SOD.ContractReceived_F, 
       SOD.DesignReview_F, 
       SOD.OrderPlotPlan_S, 
       SOD.OrderPlotPlan_F, 
       SOD.OrderTrusses_S, 
       SOD.OrderTrusses_F, 
       SOD.OrderHeatCalcs_S, 
       SOD.OrderHeatCalcs_F, 
       SOD.PermitRelease_S, 
       SOD.PermitRelease_F, 
       SOD.IntSelectionsAppt_F, 
       SOD.ExcavationFile_S, 
       SOD.ExcavationFile_F, 
       SOD.FramingFile_S, 
       SOD.FramingFile_F, 
       SOD.FinishingFile_S, 
       SOD.FinishingFile_F, 
       SOD.StartDate, 
       SOD.Possession, 
       SOD.Expected_Occupancy, 
       SOD.Description, 
       SOD.ActualFinish 
FROM   (SELECT dbo.ScheduledatesFF.Job_No, 
       dbo.ScheduledatesFF.ContractReceived_F, 
       dbo.ScheduledatesFF.DesignReview_F, 
       dbo.scheduledatesSS.OrderPlotPlan_S, 
       dbo.ScheduledatesFF.OrderPlotPlan_F, 
       dbo.scheduledatesSS.OrderTrusses_S, 
       dbo.ScheduledatesFF.OrderTrusses_F, 
       dbo.scheduledatesSS.OrderHeatCalcs_S, 
       dbo.ScheduledatesFF.OrderHeatCalcs_F, 
       dbo.scheduledatesSS.PermitRelease_S, 
       dbo.ScheduledatesFF.PermitRelease_F, 
       dbo.ScheduledatesFF.IntSelectionsAppt_F, 
       dbo.scheduledatesSS.ExcavationFile_S, 
       dbo.ScheduledatesFF.ExcavationFile_F, 
       dbo.scheduledatesSS.FramingFile_S, 
       dbo.ScheduledatesFF.FramingFile_F, 
       dbo.scheduledatesSS.FinishingFile_S, 
       dbo.ScheduledatesFF.FinishingFile_F, 
       dbo.ScheduledatesFF.StartDate, 
       dbo.ScheduledatesFF.Possession, 
       dbo.tblCustomers.Expected_Occupancy, 
       dbo.maxscheddate.Description, 
       dbo.maxscheddate.ActualFinish, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   ORDER BY dbo.ScheduledatesFF.Job_No) AS RowNum 
        FROM   dbo.ScheduledatesFF 
               INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomers 
                       ON dbo.ScheduledatesFF.Job_No = dbo.tblCustomers.Job_No 
               INNER JOIN dbo.scheduledatesSS 
                       ON dbo.ScheduledatesFF.Job_No = dbo.scheduledatesSS.Job_No 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.maxscheddate 
                            ON dbo.ScheduledatesFF.Job_No = dbo.maxscheddate.Job_No) AS SOD 
WHERE  SOD.RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

Comment: Side-note: `SOD.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 2 ` it can never be 0.

Comment: The problem is that you are using table aliases which are not available outside of the sub-query.

Comment: You will have to select all the columns in the subquery that you want to have in the outer query. No you are only selecting 5 columns in the subquery: `a.Job_No, a.ContractReceived_F, a.DesignReview_F, z.OrderPlotPlan_S, Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.Job_No) AS RowNum`.

Comment: Try to insert the SOD part into temporary table and than use that temporary table to get data from.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using table aliases which are not available outside of the sub-query. So simply remove them(or replace with `SOD`).

```
SELECT Job_No, 
       ContractReceived_F, 
       DesignReview_F, 
       OrderPlotPlan_S, 
       OrderPlotPlan_F, 
       OrderTrusses_S, 
       OrderTrusses_F, 
       OrderHeatCalcs_S, 
       OrderHeatCalcs_F, 
       PermitRelease_S, 
       PermitRelease_F, 
       IntSelectionsAppt_F, 
       ExcavationFile_S, 
       ExcavationFile_F, 
       FramingFile_S, 
       FramingFile_F, 
       FinishingFile_S, 
       FinishingFile_F, 
       StartDate, 
       Possession, 
       Expected_Occupancy AS ClosingDate, 
       Description, 
       ActualFinish       AS LastTaskCompleted 
FROM   (SELECT a.Job_No, 
               a.ContractReceived_F, 
               a.DesignReview_F, 
               z.OrderPlotPlan_S, 
               OTHER_COLUMNS ....,
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   ORDER BY a.Job_No) AS RowNum 
        FROM   dbo.ScheduledatesFF AS a 
               INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomers AS c 
                       ON a.Job_No = c.Job_No 
               INNER JOIN dbo.scheduledatesSS AS z 
                       ON a.Job_No = z.Job_No 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.maxscheddate AS m 
                            ON a.Job_No = m.Job_No) AS SOD 
WHERE  SOD.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 2
```

**Update**: there's another problem. You are selecting columns in the main query which you haven't selected in the sub-query, so they don't exist there. You need to select at least those columns you want to use in the outer query.

Comment: He can't remove aliases, if he does this won't work at all since SQL wouldn't know which column is a part of which table

Comment: @Hoh: there's only one "table", the sub-query `SOD`.

Comment: Your main query is trying to pull columns that the derived table doesn't provide.

Comment: @AndriyM: you're right. I've already mentioned that below the query. Now i've added `OTHER_COLUMNS` to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

User `Select *` instead of

```
select a.Job_No, 
               a.ContractReceived_F, 
               a.DesignReview_F, 
               z.OrderPlotPlan_S, 
               Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.Job_No) AS RowNum
```

in inner SELECT statement.

Comment: what would the full query look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SOD.Job_No, 
       SOD.ContractReceived_F, 
       SOD.DesignReview_F, 
       SOD.OrderPlotPlan_S, 
       SOD.OrderPlotPlan_F, 
       SOD.OrderTrusses_S, 
       SOD.OrderTrusses_F, 
       SOD.OrderHeatCalcs_S, 
       SOD.OrderHeatCalcs_F, 
       SOD.PermitRelease_S, 
       SOD.PermitRelease_F, 
       SOD.IntSelectionsAppt_F, 
       SOD.ExcavationFile_S, 
       SOD.ExcavationFile_F, 
       SOD.FramingFile_S, 
       SOD.FramingFile_F, 
       SOD.FinishingFile_S, 
       SOD.FinishingFile_F, 
       SOD.StartDate, 
       SOD.Possession, 
       SOD.Expected_Occupancy AS ClosingDate, 
       SOD.Description, 
       SOD.ActualFinish       AS LastTaskCompleted 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.Job_No) AS RowNum 
        FROM   dbo.ScheduledatesFF AS a 
               INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomers AS c 
                       ON a.Job_No = c.Job_No 
               INNER JOIN dbo.scheduledatesSS AS z 
                       ON a.Job_No = z.Job_No 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.maxscheddate AS m 
                            ON a.Job_No = m.Job_No) AS SOD 
WHERE  SOD.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 2
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the errors I get with this query

Comment: I get this error `Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The column 'Job_No' was specified multiple times for 'SOD'.`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are trying to retrieving columns that are not providing from the sub query. So `SELECT *` from sub query and set alias as `SOD` and get all columns that return from sub query using `SELECT [SOD].*`.

Try as follows,

```
SELECT [SOD].*
FROM   (SELECT *,
           Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.Job_No) AS RowNum 
    FROM   dbo.ScheduledatesFF AS a 
           INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomers AS c 
                   ON a.Job_No = c.Job_No 
           INNER JOIN dbo.scheduledatesSS AS z 
                   ON a.Job_No = z.Job_No 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.maxscheddate AS m 
                        ON a.Job_No = m.Job_No) [SOD] 
WHERE  [SOD].RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

Note: Row number could not be 0.

Comment: I get this error `Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The column 'Job_No' was specified multiple times for 'SOD'`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT a.Job_No, 
       a.ContractReceived_F, 
       a.DesignReview_F, 
       z.OrderPlotPlan_S, 
       a.OrderPlotPlan_F, 
       z.OrderTrusses_S, 
       a.OrderTrusses_F, 
       z.OrderHeatCalcs_S, 
       a.OrderHeatCalcs_F, 
       z.PermitRelease_S, 
       a.PermitRelease_F, 
       a.IntSelectionsAppt_F, 
       z.ExcavationFile_S, 
       a.ExcavationFile_F, 
       z.FramingFile_S, 
       a.FramingFile_F, 
       z.FinishingFile_S, 
       a.FinishingFile_F, 
       a.StartDate, 
       a.Possession, 
       c.Expected_Occupancy AS ClosingDate, 
       m.Description, 
       m.ActualFinish       AS LastTaskCompleted 
FROM   (SELECT a.Job_No, 
       a.ContractReceived_F, 
       a.DesignReview_F, 
       z.OrderPlotPlan_S, 
       a.OrderPlotPlan_F, 
       z.OrderTrusses_S, 
       a.OrderTrusses_F, 
       z.OrderHeatCalcs_S, 
       a.OrderHeatCalcs_F, 
       z.PermitRelease_S, 
       a.PermitRelease_F, 
       a.IntSelectionsAppt_F, 
       z.ExcavationFile_S, 
       a.ExcavationFile_F, 
       z.FramingFile_S, 
       a.FramingFile_F, 
       z.FinishingFile_S, 
       a.FinishingFile_F, 
       a.StartDate, 
       a.Possession, 
       c.Expected_Occupancy AS ClosingDate, 
       m.Description, 
       m.ActualFinish       AS LastTaskCompleted 
       Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.Job_No) AS RowNum 
        FROM   dbo.ScheduledatesFF AS a 
               INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomers AS c 
                       ON a.Job_No = c.Job_No 
               INNER JOIN dbo.scheduledatesSS AS z 
                       ON a.Job_No = z.Job_No 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.maxscheddate AS m 
                            ON a.Job_No = m.Job_No) AS SOD 
WHERE  SOD.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 2
```

Comment: I tried this and it first gave me an error: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 47
Incorrect syntax near 'Row_number'.` then I added a comma after As LastTaskCompleted before Row_number() and then I got the same errors as before